# Consecutive string matching in a sentence using R

Tags: r, rstudio, string-matching

I have names of some 7 countries which is stored somewhere like:

```
Random <- c('norway', 'india', 'china', 'korea', 'france','japan','iran')
```

Now, I have to find out using r if a given sentence has these words.
Sometimes the name of a country is hiding in the consecutive letters within a sentence. 
for ex:

You all must pay it bac**k, or ea**ch of you will be in trouble.

If this sentence is passed it should return "korea"

I have tried:

```
grep('You|all|must|pay|it|back|or|each|of|you|will|be|in|trouble',Random, value = TRUE,ignore.case=TRUE,
 fixed = FALSE)
```

it should return korea

but it's not working. Perhaps I should not use Partial Matching, but i dont have much knowledge regarding it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First remove the spaces and punctuation, then the matching is easy.

Comment: You mean something like this gsub(" ","", "You all must pay it back, or each of you will be in trouble " , fixed=TRUE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the handy `stringr` library for this. First, remove all the punctuation and spaces from your sentence that we want to match.

```
> library(stringr)
> txt <- "You all must pay it back, or each of you will be in trouble."
> g <- gsub("[^a-z]", "", tolower(txt))
# [1] "Youallmustpayitbackoreachofyouwillbeintrouble"
```

Then we can use `str_detect` to find the matches.

```
> Random[str_detect(g, Random)]
# [1] "korea"
```

Basically you're just looking for a sub-string within a sentence, so collapsing the sentence first seems like a good way to go.  Alternatively, you could use `str_locate` with `str_sub` to find the relevant sub-strings.

```
> no <- na.omit(str_locate(g, Random))
> str_sub(g, no[,1], no[,2])
# [1] "korea"
```

**Edit** Here's one more I came up with

```
> Random[Vectorize(grepl)(Random, g)]
# [1] "korea"
```

Comment: (+1) I was just going to post `unlist(mapply(str_extract_all, g, Random))`, but yours seem better

Comment: @1089, you may want to use `tolower` on the two vectors so that you don't need to be concerned with case-matching issues.

Comment: @RichardScriven, Yes off course. that will be a better idea.

Comment: @DavidArenburg - no need for `mapply`.  It's all vectorized. Try `Random[!is.na(str_extract(g, Random))]`

Comment: Yeah, you used a different function `str_extract`, while I used `str_extract_all`

Answer (score 1):

Using base functions only:

```
Random <- c('norway', 'india', 'china', 'korea', 'france','japan','iran')
Random2=paste(Random,collapse="|")     #creating pattern for match

text="bac**k, or ea**ch of you will be in trouble."
text2=gsub("[[:punct:][:space:]]","",text,perl=T)  #removing punctuations and space characters

regmatches(text2,gregexpr(Random2,text2))
[[1]]
[1] "korea"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `stringi` which is faster for these operations

```
library(stringi)
Random[stri_detect_regex(gsub("[^A-Za-z]", "", txt), Random)]
#[1] "korea"

#data
Random <- c('norway', 'india', 'china', 'korea', 'france','japan','iran')    
txt <- "You all must pay it back, or each of you will be in trouble."
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Random <- c('norway', 'india', 'china', 'korea', 'france','japan','iran')    
txt <- "You all must pay it back, or each of you will be in trouble."

tt  <- gsub("[[:punct:]]|\\s+", "", txt)

unlist(sapply(Random, function(r) grep(r, tt)))
korea 
    1
```